# Undefined method even after method_missing handling

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I'm studying Ruby and try to implement `method_missing`, but it's not working. For example, I want to print method name after `find_` but ruby raises "undefined method 'find_hello'" when i call it on Book instance.

TEST_05.RB

```
module Searchable
    def self.method_missing(m, *args)
        method = m.to_s
        if method.start_with?("find_")
            attr = method[5..-1]
            puts attr
        else
            super
        end
    end
end

class Book

    include Searchable

    BOOKS = []
    attr_accessor :author, :title, :year

    def initialize(name = "Undefined", author = "Undefined", year = 1970)
        @name = name
        @author = author
        @year = year
    end
end


book = Book.new
book.find_hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling method on `object` which looks for `instance_level` method. So you need to define instance_level `method_missing` method:

```
module Searchable
    def method_missing(m, *args)
        method = m.to_s
        if method.start_with?("find_")
            attr = method[5..-1]
            puts attr
        else
            super
        end
    end
end

class Book

    include Searchable

    BOOKS = []
    attr_accessor :author, :title, :year

    def initialize(name = "Undefined", author = "Undefined", year = 1970)
        @name = name
        @author = author
        @year = year
    end
end


book = Book.new
book.find_hello   #=> hello
```

When you use `self` with method definition. It is defined as `class level` method. In your case `Book.find_hello` will output `hello`.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined `method_missing` as a *class* method on `Searchable`, but you're trying to invoke it as an *instance* method.  To invoke the method as it is, run it against the class:

```
Book.find_hello
```

If your intention is to find something from the entire collection of books, this is the canonical way it's done.  ActiveRecord uses this approach.

You could similarly have a `find_*` instance method that would search the current book instance for something.  If that's your intention, then change `def self.method_missing` to `def method_missing`.